# How do you collapse and expand a complex view in android?

Tags: android

I am implementing the search functionality which consists of a search box, and a list of categories. For design purposes I have used `EditText` , `GridView` etc.

But when the activity starts I don't want all the search box to be displayed. I just want the `EditText`, and then when the `EditText` is clicked I need the view to expand, and when some other part of the screen is clicked, for example touching the `ListView` or pressing the button I need the view to collapse in its default state consisting the `EditText`.

I can use `View.GONE` or `VIEW.VISIBLE` but I want to reach a smooth animation for expanding and collapsing.

My activity_layout.xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_box"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
           >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/cv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/njoftime_item_background"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:id="@+id/sr"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                    android:padding="20dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/search_area"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/njoftime_item_background"
                        >


                        <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                            android:id="@+id/btn_search"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:background="@color/njoftime_main_color"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white"
                            android:onClick="searchPressed"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            />

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_search"
                            android:id="@+id/search_text"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:ems="20"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/njoftime_desc"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/search_categories_area"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/search_area"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                       >


                        <GridView
                            android:id="@+id/search_grid"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"

                            android:numColumns="5"
                            android:padding="4dp"
                            android:verticalSpacing="4dp" >
                        </GridView>

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

For this I have used  `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` and the following code

```
my_relative_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.search_categories_area);
```

with:

```
  public void searchPressed(View v) {
        if (!searchbox_expanded) {

            my_relative_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            searchbox_expanded = true;
        } else {
            my_relative_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            searchbox_expanded = false;

        }

    }
```

Well the expanding is really smooth animation, but the collapsing is not animated.

I have used other solutions online but I have not reached the desire effect due to the complex layout I think. Any solutions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple :

To collapse the view you only need to add an `onClickListener` on the parent view (search_box) which triggers a function to collapse the view with an `animation`.

To expand the view you need to trigger another animation to expend the view when clicking on the search `EditText`

Here is an example of animation to collapse and to expend a view:

`         import android.view.View;
          import android.view.animation.Animation;
          import android.view.animation.Transformation;

```
/**
 * Created by wajdichamakhi on 26/01/15.
 */
public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation {


  private int endHeight; // distance between start and end height
  private int endWidth; // distance between start and end width


  private View view; 

  /**
   * constructor, do not forget to use the setParams(int, int) method before
   * starting the animation
   *
   * @param v
   */
  public ResizeAnimation(View v) {
      this.view = v;
  }

  @Override
  protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

      view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (view.getHeight() + (endHeight - view.getHeight()) * interpolatedTime);
      view.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (view.getWidth() + (endWidth -   view.getWidth()) * interpolatedTime);

      view.requestLayout();
  }

  /**
   * set the starting and ending height for the resize animation
   * starting height is usually the views current height, the end height is the height
   * we want to reach after the animation is completed
   *
   * @param endWidths width in pixels
   * @param endHeight height in pixels
   */
  public void setParams(int endWidths, int endHeight) {
      this.endWidth = endWidths;
      this.endHeight = endHeight;
  }

  /**
   * set the duration for the hideshowanimation
   */
  @Override
  public void setDuration(long durationMillis) {
      super.setDuration(durationMillis);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean willChangeBounds() {
      return true;
  }

   /**
   * Verify if this animation needs to be fired or not.
   */
  public boolean isValidAnimation() {
      if (this.endWidth == view.getWidth() && this.endHeight ==  view.getHeight())
          return false;
      else
          return true;
   }
}`
```

Now you put the function that returns a set of animation which contains this animation. I work with animation set so I can add several animation at once to the view and create a cool animation.

```
 public AnimationSet getExpend_CollapseAnimationSet(final View v, int height, int width) {

    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);

        ResizeAnimation resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(v);
        resizeAnimation.setParams(
                width,
                height);
        if (resizeAnimation.isValidAnimation()) {
            resizeAnimation.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
            animationSet.addAnimation(resizeAnimation);
        }

    return animationSet;
}
```

Now use this function in your listeners with the right `width` and `height`

```
 AnimationSet initialStateAnimation = getExpend_CollapseAnimationSet(myViewToExpend_Collapse,deiredHeight, desiredWidth);
 myViewToExpend_Collapse.startAnimation(initialStateAnimation);
```

Comment: I used your solutions, and i applied it to `CardView` cv but it show no animation at all. This is the way I called it : ` my_relative_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            AnimationSet initialStateAnimation = getExpend_CollapseAnimationSet(card,card.getHeight(), card.getWidth());
            card.startAnimation(initialStateAnimation);
            searchbox_expanded = true;`

Comment: you should pass a different values than `card.height` and `card.width` cause `card ` already has that width and height.  `height` and `width`are the destination values you will reach by the animation. you should pass a different values then the initial height and width of your view.
suppose your view have height == 200 and width == 300 so to collapse it you should pass height = 0 and width = 0. and to expend you should put height = 400,  width = 500. Good Luck. and if that did help you please put the question as resolved . :)

Comment: see [this on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UWXqFBF86U) and the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html)